# XCode 9 switch between projects

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode9

I notice it is impossible to conveniently switch between projects in XCode 9. I have a Project 1 opened, then open Project 2, then to switch back to Project 1, I select 'Open Recent' and select Project 1. And to my surprise nothing happens. Is that a bug in XCode 9 and does it have a workaround?

Comment: Cmd+` to switch between windows of the same app?

Comment: Doesn't work on my Mac

Comment: @DeepakSharma Cmd+` is for switching between the windows of the currently focused application. Larme's suggestion assumes you have both projects open at the same time.

Comment: Doesn't work if one of the projects is minimized.

Answer (score 2):

You can open multiple projects using the same version of Xcode. And to switch to different projects, you can either:

1. Use multiple windows. (Swipe 4 fingers up if you're using a Macbook, then drag 1 project to a new Desktop Window.), like so:

[image]

2. OR simply press **Command + ~`**

EDIT/Addendum: Your project might be in minimized state that's why you can't switch to it.

Comment: I could switch between projects in XCode 8 using 'Recent Projects' menu, even if any of the projects was minimized. Command and ~` key pressed together do not do anything. Nor a swipe with 4 fingers does the job. Apple has done a horrible thing in my opinion to the productivity